# DIV contents not sliding properly

Tags: jquery, html, slide

I have a DIV which is a banner stretching 100% wide for the top 25px of the display. It fades into view on loading and can be removed by clicking the cross at the end and. It is set to slide out of view using JQuery. However, the contents don't slide away with it, they just disappear. Do I need to attach the same jquery to the nested DIV as well to make sure they animate correctly?

Currently using this JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* The fade in script */
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#alert_top').delay(2000).fadeIn(300);
});
/* The fade out script */
$(function(){ 
$(".alert_topClose").click(function(){
    $("#alert_top").slideUp(300, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Here is the accompanying HTML

```
<div id="alert_top">
<div class="alertcontainer">
    <div class="alertcontent alertstyle">Text</div>
    <div class="alertclose alertstyle"><a class="alert_topClose"><img src="cancel_cross_14x14_white.png" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2J7qP/

Comment: Can you reproduce at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Edited with the HTML. I'll post it at JSFiddle.

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/2J7qP/

Comment: The fiddle works for me, both Chrome and Firefox for Windows 7. They render differently, though, which is interesting. Didn't investigate the CSS, but suffice it to say that you should NOT need to bind the contents (as per your original question) but you may need to rejig your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was small issues in CSS which you provided. I fixed them and test it in FireFox, IE, Chrome and Safari and it looks fine now:

- New Update: http://jsfiddle.net/42qWt/

I change your fixed size to be flexible depends on screen width and put your close div inside alert. I changed the order of close button div because I wanted to use float:right. Please let me know if you have any question regarding this :-)